# appbar overlaps notification bar when bottom navigation bar is present

Tags: flutter, appbar

**When I navigate to the pages through the bottom navigation, the pages appbar gets overlayed by the phones notification bar.**

Page with bottom-navigation:

[image]

Same page without bottom navigation:

[image]

***I need my app-bar to look like the second picture with the bottom-navigation. When I commented on the bottom navigation the page turns back to normal.

---

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    // import 'package:flutter_ecommerce_app/main.dart';
    // import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
    import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_ecommerce_app/screens/ShoppingCartPage(p).dart';
    import 'package:flutter_ecommerce_app/screens/HomeScreen.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_ecommerce_app/screens/profilePage.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_ecommerce_app/screens/OurStores.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_ecommerce_app/screens/NotificationsScreen.dart';
    
    class BottomNavBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _BottomNavBarWidgetState createState() => new _BottomNavBarWidgetState();
    }
    
    class _BottomNavBarWidgetState extends State<BottomNavBarWidget> {
      int currentIndex = 2;
      GlobalKey _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();
      final List<Widget> viewContainer = [
        StoresNearMe(),
        notifications(),
        HomeScreen(),
        CartScreen(),
        ProfilePage()
      ];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // void onTap(int index) {
        //   setState(() {
        //     currentIndex = index;
        //   });
        // }
    
        return SafeArea(
          child: new Scaffold(
            body: viewContainer[currentIndex],
            bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
              key: _bottomNavigationKey,
              index: currentIndex,
              height: 45.0,
              items: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.menu_open),
                Icon(Icons.notifications_active_rounded),
                Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  size: 35,
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
                Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                Icon(Icons.person),
              ],
              color: Colors.grey[200],
              buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
              onTap: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  currentIndex = index;
                  print(currentIndex);
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use padding around the body.

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,),
  child: child,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It wants to apply your app style to the status bar but the SafeArea widget is preventing it. So either remove SafeAre widget or set `top:false` in SafeArea